# JAVASCRIPT only the first function is working on my window.onscroll function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement, onscroll

I am new to javascript and I am trying to make both of these functions run at different times depending on the scroll position but only the first function 'myFunction1' is running. Please help.

```js
<script>
 

window.onscroll = function redblob() {myFunction()

function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 && document.body.scrollTop < 1200 || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250  && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1200  ) {
    document.getElementById("redblob").classList.add('scale-transition');
  } 

 
  else {
    document.getElementById("redblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');
  }
  
  
}

function myFunction2() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1200 && document.body.scrollTop < 1700 || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1200  && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1700  ) {
    document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.add('scale-transition');
 
  } 

 
  else {
    document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');
 
  }
  
  
}
};
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help Daniel, as you noticed i did reuse the function name myFunction. I changed the name to function1 and added that to the first function and it worked perfectly.

```js
window.onscroll = function functionname() { myFunction2(); myFunction1(); 

function myFunction1() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 250 && document.body.scrollTop < 1200 || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250  && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1200  ) {
    document.getElementById("redblob").classList.add('scale-transition');

  } 

 
  else {
    document.getElementById("redblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');

  }
  
  
}

function myFunction2() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1200 && document.body.scrollTop < 1700 || 
  document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1200  && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1700  ) {
    document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.add('scale-transition');

  } 

 
  else {
    document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');

  }
  
  
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You were reusing the function name myFunction(). I renamed the second one to myFunction1() (this is what you said it should be named in your question) and added a function declaration before it. This caused the errors to go away.

```html
<script>
 
window.onscroll = function redblob() {
    function myFunction() {
        function myFunction1() {
            if ((document.body.scrollTop > 250) && (document.body.scrollTop < 1200) || (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 250) && (document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1200)) {
                document.getElementById("redblob").classList.add('scale-transition');
            } else {
                document.getElementById("redblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');
            }
        }

        function myFunction2() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 1200 && document.body.scrollTop < 1700 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1200 && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1700) {
                document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.add('scale-transition');
            } else {
                document.getElementById("blueblob").classList.remove('scale-transition');
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
```